# How to convert string to NSDate that has extraneous characters (swift)?

Tags: xcode, swift, nsdate

I have the string **"Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48 EST\n\t\t\t"** that I need convert to NSDate, but it gives me nil all the time.

1. I tried to clear the string by

`dateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)`

result looks fine: Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48. Converting to NSDate = **nil** :(

2. Ok, I removed the noised characters manually and try to convert the string "Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48 EST" to NSDate. **Nil again**:

`let dateString = "Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48 EST"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: 'US_en')`

`formatter.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'
print("date = \(date)")
//date = nil`

What am I doing wrong?

Even if I use "formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "EST")" still nil.

Comment: Your `dateFormat` is wrong. Read the documentation about `NSDateFormatter` and how to use date formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Answer to your first question:

You could use the following code to trim the unwanted whitespace and newlines from the string

```
var dateAsString = "Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48 EST\n\t\t"
dateAsString = dateAsString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
```

> Answer to your second question:

Refer to the Date format symbols table in this [link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-nsdate-in-swift) for list of all string formatting symbols.

You should be able to convert the specified date with this formatter,

```
let customDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"

let date = dayTimePeriodFormatter.dateFromString(dateAsString) //"Sat, 21 Nov 2015 19:20:48 EST"
```

Comment: Super! Works fine. Thank you.